# How to overcome the error Subquery returns more than 1 row in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all employee names who earn more than average salary of all employees of **their company**.

This is the database

```
create table works(
employee_name varchar (100) primary key,
company_name varchar (100),
salary int (6) );
```

This is the code I used,

```
select employee_name
from works
where salary > (select avg(salary) from works group by company_name)
group by company_name;
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a group by in the subquery, you just need a where clause:

```
SELECT employee_name
FROM works w
WHERE salary > (select avg(salary) from works w2 where w2.company_name = w.company_name);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was stucked in this code for many days. Thank you again.

Comment: That's great. Always up for help @Tharaka

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a group by in the outer select, but you have to add a `where` clause to the inner `select`.

> ```
> create table works(
> employee_name varchar (100) primary key,
> company_name varchar (100),
> salary int (6) );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO works VALUES ('a','comp A',100),('a2','comp A',150),('a3','comp A',250),('a4','comp B',100)
> ,('a5','comp B',300),('a6','comp B',200)
> ```

> ```
> select employee_name,company_name,salary
> from works w1
> where salary >= (select avg(salary) avgsal from works w2 WHERE w1.company_name = w2.company_name 
> group by company_name
> )
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> employee_name | company_name | salary
> :------------ | :----------- | -----:
> a3            | comp A       |    250
> a5            | comp B       |    300
> a6            | comp B       |    200
> ```

> ```
> select avg(salary) avgsal from works w2  
> group by company_name
> ```
>
> ```
> |   avgsal |
> | -------: |
> | 166.6667 |
> | 200.0000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6367efa0218fe3675fd24b3f7adabff5)*